# Im running into InterfaceError from SQLAlchemy after trying to update a profile pic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

-- This is the error Im getting --

```
InterfaceError
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: UPDATE user SET image_file=? WHERE user.id = ?]
[parameters: (<FileStorage: 'default.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, 6)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

-- This is my code for saving a picture into the app folder  --

```
def save_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/profile_pics/' + picture_fn)
    form_picture.save(picture_path)
    
    return picture_fn
```

-- This is the route where Im calling the save_picture function --

```
@app.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            picture_file = save_picture(form.picture.data)
            current_user.image_file = form.picture.data

        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been updated', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('account'))
        
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
    return render_template("account.html", title="MY BLOG", image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

After debbug I got that the db.session.commit() is calling the error, but I checked many times and  still dont understand where is the problem. The picture is getting saved in the app's folder, but is not getting saved into the database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I was making the wrong attributions to the `current.user.image_file`,
I needed to attribute `current.user.image_file` with the `picture_file` I saved and renamed with the `secrets.token_hex(8)` not the one I got from the open file inside the webpage

```
if form.picture.data:
            picture_file = save_picture(form.picture.data)
            current_user.image_file = picture_file
```